# How can I have my map open in the center of my visitors IP address?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, address

I have a map of all restaurants in Florida. I would like to have the center of the map be the address of the visitors IP. How can I do this?

Comment: It may be helpful to describe your server environment in detail.

Comment: Expanding Blah238's comment, can you tell us what is the API that you are using? Would your clients visit your site through a mobile, or through a web browser? the answer to your question would very much depend on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232516/geocode-an-ip-address then convert the response location to your spatial reference if you need to. zoom the map.

simple.

IP location is pretty broad though, so using the geolocation api would be more accurate.